# How to use the return value from a method

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have looked for the answer to this question but could only find answers for the java language. 
I have made a method in a class that returns either true or false,and if the method returns true,I want to use the true value in an if statement. I don't understand how to use the returned value.

Heres the method:

```
public bool endwall(Control player, Control endblock)
    {
        bool answer;
        if (player.Right > endblock.Left && player.Left < endblock.Right - player.Width / 2 && player.Bottom > endblock.Top)
        {
            answer = true;
            return answer;
        }
        else { answer = false; return answer; }
    }
```

To summarize,I pretty much want to use `answer` in my main code(to write an if statement with it),but i'm not sure how to access it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
bool returnedValue =  endwall(controlPlayer, controlEndblock);   
if(returnedValue)
{
    //code if returns true
}
else
{
    //code if returns false
}
```

Comment: i don't know what you are asking for! whatever, updated the answer. write code and check yourself.